# Is it possible to see why Windows thinks there's no internet?

Tags: networking, windows-10

Windows says my internet is out (when I click the wifi button in my tray by the clock, it says "No internet, secured"). For some reason, everything works fine except for the Spotify desktop client. Is it possible to see why Windows thinks there's no internet (even though I'm posting this from the "disconnected" computer)? All the information I could find online was for people who didn't know how to use a computer (use the troubleshooter, restart your computer, etc).

Is there a logfile somewhere that can confirm what the problem is? I suspect Spotify has the same problem as windows, and Spotify doesn't have a logfile with this level of detail.

I thought this was a problem with my DNS, but when I switched from a DoH client to 8.8.8.8 and it didn't fix anything. However, I am not sure what services/etc the DoH client is running, and I couldn't be 100% sure I totally shut them all off (for example, if there's some service that tries to intercept DNS requests, I wouldn't have found it).

I didn't see anything wrong when I ran `ipconfig /all` (the IP matched the static IP I assigned in my router, etc)

I can still use open.spotify.com (the web player), but Spotify Connect (which shows what you are playing on other devices) doesn't load. Normally, it would show the song I'm playing on the desktop client and say "Now Playing on (My comptuer)", and not let me play other songs.

`nslookup spotify.com`, `ping spotify.com`, and `ping 35.186.224.25` (which is the IP that nslookup spotify.com gave me, so it should be the same as the previous command) all output expected results.

Comment: If you suspect your DNS, have you tried changing, your DNS configuration to another service?

Comment: If you suspect your DNS, have you tried changing, your DNS configuration to another service?  Instead of submitting a temporary comment you should edit your question.  **Simply remove that statement from your question, will not change my question to you, or change my expectation of you trying that solution.**  There are many tools that can be used to diagnose your problem.  The information from `ipconfig /all` would be extremely helpful in a case like this.

Comment: @Ramhound That's a good point. I switched from a DoH client to 8.8.8.8 and it didn't fix anything. The reason I mentioned it in my question is because I am not sure what services/etc the DoH client is running, and I couldn't be 100% sure I totally shut them all off (for example, if there's some service that tries to intercept DNS requests, I wouldn't' have found it). That's why I was hoping for a log file, because it would probably point me in the right direction.

Comment: I took it out of the question because I thought it wasn't relevant anymore :)

Comment: You should provide that information in the body of your question instead of a comment.  As you add that relevant information, be sure to mention if you can ping one of IP addresses used by Spotify (specifically it's main domain) and if `nslookup` returns the proper address for it.

Comment: Ok I did that, thanks for helping me make it higher quality 